# Warning: Error in [: object of type 'environment' is not subsettable after adding crosstalk::SharedData$new() in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('brush_info')),
    column(6, plotOutput('x1', height = 500)),
    column(6, plotlyOutput('plot1', height = 500))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Subset the iris dataset based on species
  subsetted <- reactive({
    iris_subset <- subset(iris, Species == "setosa") # Change the species as needed
    iris_subset
    crosstalk::SharedData$new(iris_subset)


  })
    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({ 
    p <- ggplot(subsetted(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
      geom_point(alpha = 0.5)
    
    # Wrap ggplot object with ggplotly and apply highlight settings
    ggplotly(p) %>% 
      highlight("plotly_selected", selectize = TRUE, dynamic = TRUE)
  })
    
  output$brush_info <- DT::renderDataTable({
    subsetted()
  }, server = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 50))
  
  output$x1 <- renderPlot({
    # s <- input$x1_rows_selected
    ggplot(subsetted()[input$brush_info_rows_selected, ], aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
      geom_bar()
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The provided code is a Shiny application that displays the iris dataset and allows for brushing and selection of data points in (1) a table, (2) a scatter plot (plot1) and (3) a bar plot (x1). It shows error Warning: Error in [: object of type 'environment' is not subsettable after adding crosstalk::SharedData$new(iris_subset). Only table and scatter plot are reacting to brushing.

[image]

However, if I removed crosstalk::SharedData$new(iris_subset), it prevents the scatter plot (plot1) from reacting to brushing. Only updates table and bar plot.

[image]

What I expected is to achieve the functionality where selecting points in the scatter plot (plot1) updates the bar plot (x1), as well as the 'brush_info' table.